# Resize columns of a ASP.NET Gridview beyond its data length

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I have a web page which contains grid views and want to add the resize feature for its columns. I managed to do it using javascript but cannot reduce the size of columns beyond the max data length of that column. It seems some property of the gridview prevents their column width being shrinked beyond the max data length.

I tried using styles such as

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

but unable to get it done since these only handle the representation of data once the column size is changed. Could someone please provide me some guidance? 
Thanks a lot.

Here is part of the code...

```
<asp:MultiView ID="uxMainMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
<asp:View ID="uxHistoryView" runat="server">
    <asp:MultiView ID="uxCaseSearchResultMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="uxFlatView" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="uxCaseSearchGrid" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px" CssClass="grid"
                Width="100%" OnInit="uxCaseSearchGrid_Init" OnRowDataBound="uxCaseSearchGrid_RowDataBound"
                AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" OnPageIndexChanging="uxCaseSearchGridPageIndexChanging"
                OnSorting="uxCaseSearchGridViewSorting" OnDataBound="uxCaseSearchGrid_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

                <RowStyle CssClass="gridRowLarge" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridAltRowLarge" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeaderLarge noLink" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at what all CSS are getting applied for that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about adding a **min-width** property to your css:

```
min-width:0;
```

Allow the column cell(s) to be re-size at runtime.

Comment: It didn't work friend :( if you know any other styles please post.

Comment: can you share your rendered html for gridview?

Comment: I added some of it. Thanks Sunny for your time.